# ValueError: time data '(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 14, 14, 18, 233000),)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, datetime, format, valueerror

I'm trying to program a script that pulls data from SQL and push it into Quickbase. I only need Year, Month, and Day from my rows

here's the output from print result

```py
(datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 19, 52, 32, 927000),)
(None,)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 21, 39, 37, 163000),)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 20, 14, 23, 133000),)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 21, 31, 21, 853000),)
(datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 21, 26, 51, 307000),)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 20, 20, 35, 29, 997000),)
(datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 15, 29, 22, 967000),)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 21, 57, 3, 307000),)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 21, 28, 23, 60000),)
```

Here is what I have

```py
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    print(result)
    result = datetime.strptime(str(result), '%Y-%m-%d')



    #client.edit_record(rid = result , fields = {'99' : '1' }, database=CONTACTS_TABLE)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

heres my error

```
ValueError: time data '(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 14, 14, 18, 233000),)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have the problem that you are trying to convert a tuple to str, that is not the problem but that don't help you.

I recommend do something like this if you want to save a str:

```
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    print(result)
    result = '%d-%d-%d' % (result[0].year, result[0].month, result[0].day)
```

or if you want to save a date object, just create a new datetime.date with that values

Comment: thanks it worked, can you give me an instance where it deals with null/None values inside the datetime and how to parse/skip that?

Comment: I'll write something like:
```if result[0]:
    result = ... ```

Answer (score 0):

you have some troubles trying to manage that data structure.

You don't need to cast to `string`, so this part is bad:

```
datetime.strptime(str(result), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

You should access to the first element of the tuples and then use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> dd = (datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 19, 52, 32, 927000),)
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(dd[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
'2018-11-30'
```